# Manage in Java an arraylist using off heap memory

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following issue:
My app is loading a bunch of images (more than 10000). All of the images are stored in an ArrayList which consumes allot of heap memory (4GB actually - each image is one element in the arraylist) but I do not need them all in memory.

From the JavaFX GUI I know exactly which elements are actually shown and Javafx is manageing the GUI elements automatically (off heap memory) but the Arraylist behind is the issue.
Is therea a way that I can load all the element into the ArrayList but somehow "move" the not visible elements off the heap memory ?

Is there an ArrayList I can use which is doing this automatically like JavaFX is doing it with the ListView elements ?

Comment: You should be able to load the image files only when you need them and not store each one in a giant list. If you know when you will need an image then you can load it a second before and store it temporarily, which is a better solution. However it is really hard to recommend anything without knowing more about the environment.

Comment: Thanks. It brings me to an idea I had already in mind but I was not sure if a lib exists which is doing that in background and I want s as void double implementation.